# MOSFET SOA: Isn't the package current limit-line ambient temperature dependent?

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, fuses, thermal, packages

[Ref 1](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ApplicationNote_Linear_Mode_Operation_Safe_Operation_Diagram_MOSFETs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30433e30e4bf013e3646e9381200) says "The package limit-line will not change in case application conditions such as ambient
temperature vary"

As explained in [Ref2](https://www.vishay.com/docs/74670/74670.pdf), this limit is due to bond wire heating/melting.

If so shouldn't it depend on ambient temperature as with any thermal damage process -Even a fuse will blow/melt faster in higher ambient temperature conditions.

[image]

Comment: Ref 1 link seems broken.

Comment: Fixed. thanks for informing

Comment: Recently I have read, that electromigration can also be a limiting factor, but I'm not an expert there.

Comment: @Jens Electromigration is usually more of in issue with the metallization on the die, not the package or bond wires/clips.  It's also strongly temperature dependent.  Maybe they are just putting a max limit on the package current assuming the part may be used under any of the allowable conditions on the datasheet.